# I can't figure out how to get my javascript onclick event to work

Tags: javascript

When I click on the button nothing happens unless I call the function in the html. I am trying to remove all inline javascript. I have included the commented-out section of html that works. Thanks in advance for the help!

**JavaScript:**

```
var welcomeString;
const TEST = 1;

function setWelcomeString() {
    "use strict";
    welcomeString = prompt("Please enter your name: ", "nobody");
}

function writeOutput() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello, " + welcomeString;
}

function main() {
    "use strict";
    setWelcomeString();
    document.getElementById("sayHi").onclick = writeOutput();
}

main();
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>**SET TITLE**</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="firstScript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 id="wiggles">TEMPLATE</h1>
        <!--<button id="sayHi" onclick="writeOutput()">Say Hi</button>-->
        <button id="sayHi">Say Hi</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Look. http://jsfiddle.net/manueru_mx/Dmspc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a function as a handler for an event, you need to assign the function itself, not execute the function and assign it's return value as you are doing. Change this:

```
document.getElementById("sayHi").onclick = writeOutput(); // parens
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("sayHi").onclick = writeOutput; // no parens
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kunjee/yYYSh/1/) with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your whole code inside `load`, like this

```
window.load = function(){
    // your javascript here
};
```

Also, as jbabey mentioned, use either

```
document.getElementById("sayHi").onclick = function(){ writeOutput();};
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("sayHi").onclick = writeOutput;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.

The first being covered by jbabey.

The second is that firstScript.js appears before your button. This is problematic as when you are assigning the `onClick` handler to it. It doesn't exist in the dom.

Try putting the entire main script inside `window.onload = function () { ... }` or moving it to the bottom of the markup.